Изменить вхождения vscode
В vscode на мак ос есть полезная горячая клавиша ⌘ cmd+F2 она заменяет все упоминания имя выделенной переменной. Один недостаток что она делает это во всем файле. В пайчарм эту замену можно сделать только внутри блока, функции и тд. Есть ли что-то подобное в vscode?

Ctrl+F2 не заменяет переменную. Эта команда заменяет слово под курсором. Словом может всё что угодно. Эта команда не знает ничего о языке программирования и работает с программой как с обычным текстом.
Если вам нужно работать именно с переменными, то ваш выбор - F2, команда Rename Symbol. Это очень крутая команда,которая умеет работать практически со всеми языками программирования. Она меняет имя символа (переменной, функции, метода, класса и т.д.) во всей области видимости. Если ваша переменная объявлена в блоке, то заменит в блоке. Если в функции - заменит в функции. Самый цимес, когда переменная глобальная. Тогда эта команда может (в зависимости от языка) найти все использования переменной в других файлах и поменять имя в них тоже.

Есть несколько вариантов:

F2 — переименовать переменную. Наводишь курсор на нужную переменную и жмешь, он автоматически ищет ее во всем файле, но по умолчанию выделяет только блок.



Ctrl + D — выделяет слово, на котором находится курсор. Следующее нажатие на D (удерживая Ctrl) выделить следующее по порядку вниз идентичное значение.

P.S. Забыл, что ты писал про мак, у тебя тоже должно быть тоже самое, только ⌘ cmd вместо ctrl
